# how to stream a streamable video from a google storage bucket with expo-av video element on react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, video, expo-av

I need to stream a video with the expo-av video component on react native.

The issue I'm having is that it has to download the entire video before it starts playing.

It needs to stream the video and play immediately and not after it downloads the video first

### Video component

```js
<Video
  ref={video}
  source={{uri:viewOptionsVideoURL}}            
  style={{ width:windowWidth, height: "50%"}}
  resizeMode={ResizeMode.STRETCH}
  isLooping
  useNativeControls
  onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
  rate={1.0}
  volume={1.0}
  isMuted={false}
  onLoad={(status: AVPlaybackStatus)=>{
      console.log(status);
  }}
  onError={console.log}
/>
```

### Calling Code

```js
// this will set the video url on the above component using the useState hook
setViewOptionsVideoURL("https://storage.googleapis.com/clipdrop-prod/tfNttNC2RLuuxJ_VdWKKcJkm1.amgZR6y_460sv.mp4");
// these 2 will load and start playing the video from position 0
await (video?.current as any).loadAsync();
await (video?.current as any).playFromPositionAsync(0);
```

Not sure what else to do, as I would like it to start playing as soon as its loaded as the above invocation of the video using loadAsync()